# ¿Cómo se espera a que termine un objeto Future resultante de una llamada a una API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, async-await, asyncio

Estoy intentando esperar los resultados de una consulta a la api de mi chatbot gradio pero no se como hacerlo. Me refiero a esperar a que se complete un objeto Future. Pensé que .result() esperaría los resultados pero no es el caso. En efecto, el codigo siguiente me da este error:

```
(.venv) project@project-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/dev/project/chatbot-rag$ python3 test_questions.py 
Loaded as API: http://0.0.0.0:7860/ ✔
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/dev/project/chatbot-rag/test_questions.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(response.data)
  File "/home/project/dev/project/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio_client/client.py", line 1561, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.future, name)
AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Aqui es el codigo:

```
from gradio_client import Client
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime

client = Client("http://0.0.0.0:7860/")

# Charger les questions depuis le fichier JSON
with open('/media/HELLO/SanDisk/Clef_rag/project/questions.json', 'r') as file:
    questions_data = json.load(file)

# Initialiser une liste pour stocker les réponses
responses_data = []

# Générer le nom de fichier horodaté
current_time = datetime.now()
timestamp = current_time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H:%M")
filename = f'/media/HELLO/SanDisk/Clef_rag/project/responses_{timestamp}.json'

# Traiter chaque question
for domain, questions in questions_data.items():
    if domain == 'QR_TI_technique':
        for question in questions:
            # Récupérer la question
            question_text = question["question"]

            # Enregistrer l'heure de début
            start_time = time.time()

            # Soumettre la question au modèle
            response = client.submit(question_text, api_name="/bot")
            # wait(response)
            data = response.result()
            
            # Enregistrer l'heure de fin
            end_time = time.time()

            # Calculer la durée
            duration = end_time - start_time

            # Stocker les données de réponse
            response_data = {
                "domaine": domain,
                "question": question_text,
                "reponse_attendue": question["reponse_attendue"],
                "reponse_model": response.data,
                "heure_debut": start_time,
                "heure_fin": end_time,
                "duree": duration
            }

            # Ajouter les données de réponse à la liste
            responses_data.append(response_data)

            # Enregistrer les réponses après chaque itération dans le fichier horodaté
            with open(filename, 'a') as file:
                json.dump(response_data, file, indent=4)
                file.write('\n')  # Ajouter une nouvelle ligne pour chaque réponse
```

## Actualizacion:

Intenté modificar lo que obtengo en reponse_model por:

```
            "reponse_model": data,
```

Pero parece que el problema ya está ahí cuando intento llegar a la respuesta con `data = response.result()`

```
(.venv) cert@cert-GE66-Raider-11UH:~/dev/CERT/chatbot-rag$ python3 test_questions.py 
Loaded as API: http://0.0.0.0:7860/ ✔
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cert/dev/CERT/chatbot-rag/test_questions.py", line 33, in <module>
    data = response.result()
  File "/home/cert/dev/CERT/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio_client/client.py", line 1456, in result
    return super().result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/cert/dev/CERT/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio_client/client.py", line 869, in _inner
    predictions = _predict(*data)
  File "/home/cert/dev/CERT/chatbot-rag/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gradio_client/client.py", line 896, in _predict
    raise ValueError(result["error"])
ValueError: None
```

¿Es el contenido de `response.result()` el problema?

Answer (score 1):

El [método `gradio.Job.result()`](https://www.gradio.app/docs/job) es bloqueante y espera a que exista una respuesta (o se cumpla el `timeout` o se cancele el trabajo), **retornando los datos del resultado**. En esencia `Job` es una sublclase de [concurrent.futures.Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future).

El problema es que estas intentando acceder al resultado de la consulta usando el objeto `Job` con `response.data`, cuando los datos de la respuesta los tienes en la salida de `response.result()`, es decir, tu variable `data`. En principio (desconozco la naturaleza/tipo de los datos que recibes como respuesta) en vez de:

```
"reponse_model": response.data,
```

debería ser simplemente:

```
"reponse_model": data,
```

Comment: FJ, me hace tan feliz tener algunas de tus novedades... ¿Cómo estás? hablemos en el chat !! --- Lamentablemente, sí tuve el error que mencionas de obtener el resultado con response.data, pero el error que se disparó está más arriba. En el intento de obtener response.result()